# How do I disable CORS in kue?

Tags: node.js, kue

I want to export Kue-api ( hosted on `localhost:3001` ) and access it via node-express ( hosted on `localhost:3000` ). But it is blocked because of CORS . In a typical node app , CORS can be disabled like this.

```
 var cors = require('cors');
    app.use(cors());
```

But kue in tern uses express and app is not exposed. So question is **how to disable CORS in Kue**

I tried this

```
 //----- kue-app.js-----
    var webApp = express();
    var cors = require('cors');
    webApp.use(kue.app);
    webApp.use(kue.app.cros());
    webApp.listen(3001);
```

Comment: You have CORS backwards. The Same Origin policy blocks cross origin communication by default. CORS turns it off.

Answer (score 2):

Solved - like this

```
    var webApp = express();
    var cors = require('cors');
    webApp.use(cors());
    webApp.use(kue.app);
    webApp.listen();
```